# Нахождение max и min из промежутка случайных чисел

Tags: javascript

Нужно найти максимальное и минимальное числf из промежутка случайных чисел. Через метод `Math.min` выдает `NaN` - в чем ошибка?

```
function rand(num1, num2, numbers) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (num2 - num1)) + num1;
}

var begin, end, numbers, string, curent_num, min, max;
begin = +prompt('First');
end = +prompt('Second');
numbers = +prompt('Numbers');
string = ' ';
for (var i = 1; i <= numbers; i++) {
  curent_num = rand(begin, end);
  string += curent_num + ' ';
  min = Math.min(string);
  max = Math.max(string);
}
document.write(string + " " + min + ' ' + max);
```

Comment: Math.min и Math.max не работают со строками, используйте массив. И вынесите их из цикла, нет смысла искать значения при каждом проходе

Comment: Они и с массивами не всегда хорошо работают. Вот статья на эту тему.
[Cсылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/find-the-min-max-element-of-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: у вас неверное количество параметров при вызове функций, неверный тип данных, неверная область видимости. В общем все не верно. В топку.

Answer (score 2):

1. `Math.min` и `Math.max` на передачу им строки `"1 2"` вернут `NaN` (при попытке преобразовать строку в **одно** число). Поэтому в данном случае стоит работать с числами напрямую, сравнивая сгенерированное число с уже имеющимся минимумом/максимумом
2. Подобный подход с `Math.round` для генерации случайных чисел даст неравные вероятности для всех вариантов. В частности, для границ вероятность будет вдвое меньше. Такой проблемы нет при использовании `Math.floor` вместе с `max - min + 1`
3. По самому коду: не стоит экономить на пробелах; также по названиям переменных должно быть понятно для чего они нужны, а объявлять их стоит по мере необходимости, а не скопом в начале кода; использовать `document.write` не стоит

Итоговый вариант кода:

```js
function rand(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var lowerBound = +prompt("Lower bound");
var upperBound = +prompt("Upper bound");
var numbersCount = +prompt("Numbers count");
var min = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
var max = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
var randomNumbers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numbersCount; i++) {
  var randomNumber = rand(lowerBound, upperBound);
  randomNumbers.push(randomNumber);
  min = Math.min(randomNumber, min);
  max = Math.max(randomNumber, max);
}
console.log(randomNumbers);
console.log(min + " " + max);
```

---

И вариант покороче с использованием более современных конструкций языка:

```js
function rand(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var lowerBound = +prompt("Lower bound");
var upperBound = +prompt("Upper bound");
var numbersCount = +prompt("Numbers count");
var randomNumbers = Array(numbersCount).fill().map(() => rand(lowerBound, upperBound));
var min = Math.min(...randomNumbers);
var max = Math.max(...randomNumbers);
console.log(randomNumbers);
console.log(min + " " + max);
```

Comment: _Math.min и Math.max работают с числами, а не строками_ - аргументы всегда переводятся в число, поэтому если в строке будет нормальное число - все будет ок